# How to get key in complex json file c#/ with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
{
    "product": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000001"
            },
            "product_name": "sildenafil citrate",
            "supplier": "Wisozk Inc",
            "quantity": 261,
            "unit_cost": "$10.47"
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000002"
            },
            "product_name": "Mountain Juniperus ashei",
            "supplier": "Keebler-Hilpert",
            "quantity": 292,
            "unit_cost": "$8.74"
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000003"
            },
            "product_name": "Dextromathorphan HBr",
            "supplier": "Schmitt-Weissnat",
            "quantity": 211,
            "unit_cost": "$20.53"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to get the keys of a complex json file with Newtonsoft?

I do not understand how to get the keys in a json and not since a json hard in the code:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JObjectProperties.htm

I use this methods to read my json:

it's ok for reading from a json, but I still can not get all the keys / properties
 _id/product_name/supplier/quantity/unit_cost

```
        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"products.json"))
        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
        {
            JObject o2 = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
            //WriteLine(o2.GetValue("product"));

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> property in o2)
            {
                WriteLine(property.Value[0]);
            }
        }
```

done:

```
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000001"
            },
            "product_name": "sildenafil citrate",
            "supplier": "Wisozk Inc",
            "quantity": 261,
            "unit_cost": "$10.47"
        },
```

but I want to get that only Field Names:
_id 
product_name
supplier
quantity
unit_cost

I wish something like this: but it does not seem to work in my code:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1175341/Extract-Json-Fields

Thanks,

Comment: I suspect you want to load your JSON into a JObject, rather than deserializing it into your own custom class. (Use `JObject.Parse` instead of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>`.)

Comment: yes, I just do not understand how to use this: JObject o = JObject.Parse(json); 
because currently at the click of a button I load each time the complete json in an object and I run it. What I think is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

The [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1175341/Extract-Json-Fields) provided by OP, list of keys can be fetched like:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("Json_1.json"))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();        
    var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
    foreach (var o in obj)
    {
        var result = GetFieldNames(o.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

`GetFieldNames()`:

```
public static List<string> GetFieldNames(dynamic input)
{
    List<string> fieldNames = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        // Deserialize the input json string to an object
        input = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input);

        // Json Object could either contain an array or an object or just values
        // For the field names, navigate to the root or the first element
        input = input.Root ?? input.First ?? input;

        if (input != null)
        {
            // Get to the first element in the array
            bool isArray = true;
            while (isArray)
            {
                input = input.First ?? input;

                if (input.GetType() == typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject) || 
                input.GetType() == typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue) || 
                input == null)
                    isArray = false;
            }

            // check if the object is of type JObject. 
            // If yes, read the properties of that JObject
            if (input.GetType() == typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject))
            {
                // Create JObject from object
                Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject inputJson = 
                    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.FromObject(input);

                // Read Properties
                var properties = inputJson.Properties();

                // Loop through all the properties of that JObject
                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    // Check if there are any sub-fields (nested)
                    // i.e. the value of any field is another JObject or another JArray
                    if (property.Value.GetType() == typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject) || 
                    property.Value.GetType() == typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray))
                    {
                        // If yes, enter the recursive loop to extract sub-field names
                        var subFields = GetFieldNames(property.Value.ToString());

                        if (subFields != null && subFields.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            // join sub-field names with field name 
                            //(e.g. Field1.SubField1, Field1.SubField2, etc.)
                            fieldNames.AddRange(
                                subFields
                                .Select(n =>
                                string.IsNullOrEmpty(n) ? property.Name :
                             string.Format("{0}.{1}", property.Name, n)));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If there are no sub-fields, the property name is the field name
                        fieldNames.Add(property.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                if (input.GetType() == typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue))
            {
                // for direct values, there is no field name
                fieldNames.Add(string.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }

    return fieldNames;
}
```

[image]

Comment: but my question in how to get the keys? without knowing them, ie by reading the json without doing -> products.MyKey
Is there not a way to recover these keys automatically?
Because your code is fine, but it only gives the value of the keys, which I already do.

Comment: @yave Do you want a Dictionary?

Comment: @ FaizanRabbani
a native method to newtonsoft exist it to simply recover the keys and not their value? So in my case I would like: properties _id / product_name / supplier / quantity / unit_cost

Comment: @yave see my updated answer and let  me know if it helps

Comment: not at all. I will explain Extract Json Fields: I seek to recover just the properties:properties _id / product_name / supplier / quantity / unit_cost  without naming them. i edit my post  WriteLine(property.Value[0]??properties_name??);

Comment: something like that, but more simple: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1175341/Extract-Json-Fields

Comment: the method sees me nothing. I have no errors or execption, just nothing; because i use a complexe json products.product ?

Comment: @yave it is working fine for me. I have tried your JSON

Comment: @yave I have also shown the method and attached a screenshot as well in my answer.

Comment: @yave Can you debug and see which line of code crashes?

Comment: it's work ! thanks you very much FaizanRabbani !! 
I just had a problem with my IDE!

Comment: @yave it was a learning curve for me as well, so thank you too. :-)

Comment: only small concern, when I loop List I get products._id etc how to remove the "products"? To get only the Fields

Comment: @ FaizanRabbani Great ;) Thanks a lot